# Intel Realsense 3d Webcam doesn't work correctly in Chrome or Skype on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, skype, webcam

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I have a problem with my webcam. I have this Intel Realsense 3d Cam. So, there are basically two webcams, one is a normal colored one and the other one is green-coloured.
Using cheese, I checked the normal one and it worked fine. When I try and use my Webcam in Chrome (for example in tinychat), Chrome always uses the green one, even though I try checking the other in the settings.

Moreover, when I use my Webcam in Skype, my and the person I called's video starts flimmering blue.

I hope somebody can help me.

P.S.: I'd be happy with just deactiving the green one. I don't use the 3D-option anyway. It is the built-in camera.

Answer (score 0):

With the version of skype that I have (8.18.0.6) under audio & video options you can choose the camera you want.